# Stacking text directly below an image, using a media query, on browser resize

Tags: html, css, media-queries

So I have some text which sits, next (right floated) to an image within the **footer** area of my document. When I re-size my browser to a `min-width:768px`.

I'm trying to get the text, and image to both be centrally aligned and with the image to be positioned above the text, but I can't seem to do it. All that happens is, the image shrinks to a dot and neither re-align.

Here is an example to what I'm trying to achieve, and my existing code:

[image]

**HTML :**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <footer id="page_footer">
       <p>Thanks for visiting</p>
         <a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt=
        "nffc_logo" src="images/logo.png"></a>
    </footer>
</div><!-- wrapper -->
```

---

**CSS :**

```
 #page_footer {    
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
     position: absolute;
     bottom:0;     /*sticky footer*/
     left: 0;  
     background: #282828;
     color: white;
}
#page_footer img {
     max-width: 3%;
     height:auto;             
     margin: 5px;
     float:right;                               
}             
#page_footer p {
     float:right;
     margin-right: 10px;
     margin-left: 1px;             
}
```

---

and then an empty media query :

```
@media screen and (min-width:768px) {  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added an additional container for a link and paragraph, `.right-div` and made it `float: right;` so you don't need to float it's children ( `p` and `a` ). They only need to be displayed as inline blocks, and have width or max-width for better positioning.

Please notice that i've applied styles to `a`, not to `img`

So here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5Jhxa/1/)

Comment: text is fine, however the .png image I'm using then starts off as basically a dot and is unrecognizable and appears right of text

Comment: Maybe you're applying styles ( max-width: 3%; for example ) to <img> tag?

Answer (score 0):

changing the order of your markup to (*showing image first and `<p>` after it*), solves the problem in simplest form:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <footer id="page_footer"> 
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
     <img alt="nffc_logo" src="http://www.jonathanjeter.com/images/Square_200x200.png" />
    </a>
    <p>Thanks for visiting</p>
  </footer>
</div>
<!-- wrapper -->
```

...here is a solution  [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dh9D6/1/)

**CSS**

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
    #page_footer {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        position: absolute;
        bottom:0;
        /*sticky footer*/
        left: 0;
        background: #282828;
        color: white;
        text-align:center;
    }
    #page_footer img {
        max-width: 3%;
    }
    #page_footer p {
        margin:0 auto;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
    #page_footer {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        position: absolute;
        bottom:0;
        /*sticky footer*/
        left: 0;
        background: #282828;
        color: white;
        text-align:center;
    }
    #page_footer img {
        max-width: 3%;
        vertical-align:middle
    }
    #page_footer p {
        display:inline-block;
    }
}
```

**what and how ??** to align `<p>` next to image use `display:inline-block;` method for alignment.

to align one above the other, simple `margin` would do.